# What causes clang: error: unsupported option '-V -isystem/usr/local/include' with brew

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying install freetds with brew install homebrew/versions/freetds091, but met this error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-V -isystem/usr/local/include'
```

this is the detail of config.log

> configure:3787: clang --version >&5 Apple LLVM version 7.3.0
>   (clang-703.0.31) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
>   configure:3798: $? = 0 configure:3787: clang -v >&5 Apple LLVM version
>   7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
>   configure:3798: $? = 0 configure:3787: clang -V >&5 clang: error:
>   unsupported option '-V
>   -isystem/usr/local/include' configure:3798: $? = 1 configure:3787: clang -qversion >&5 clang: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
>   configure:3798: $? = 1 configure:3818: checking whether the C compiler
>   works configure:3840: clang    conftest.c  >&5 ld: unexpected token:
>   !tapi-tbd-v2 file
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd'
>   for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I already install xcode(version 8.0)
There is a strange doubtful point: xcode 8.0's clang version is 8.0, but brew use 7.x.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang -v
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

*I solved it after I update my system to macOS Sierra.*

Comment: I hope you don't have anything that depends on scrolling actually working :(   Sierra is a mess.  I just reinstalled elcapitan

Comment: In fact, I don't know what's happened, But I know after I upgrade to Sierra, /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/Clang's version is 8.0, but before I upgrade, xcode version is 8.0, but /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/Clang's version is 7.0, that's the key